# ¿Como puedo poner una notificación cuando se agreguen nuevas fotos desde firebase a mi RecyclerView como se muestra en la imagen adjunta?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

[image: Quiero que aparezca asi:]

**Este es mi Adapdator**

```
public class Myadaptador extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<Myadaptador.ViewHolder> {


    private static Bitmap bitmap_transfer;

    public static Bitmap getBitmap_transfer() {
        return bitmap_transfer;
    }

    public static void setBitmap_transfer(Bitmap bitmap_transfer_param) {
        bitmap_transfer = bitmap_transfer_param;
    }


    private Context context;

    private List<Upload> subidas;


    Activity activity = (Activity) context;


    public Myadaptador(Context context, List<Upload> subidas) {

        this.subidas = subidas;
        this.context = context;


    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_images, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        Upload upload = subidas.get(position);

        holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(upload.getImageUrl())
                .into(holder.imageView);


    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return subidas.size();
}

 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

     public TextView textViewName;
     public ImageView imageView;
     public Button compartir;


     public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
         super(itemView);

         compartir = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.compartir);
         textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
         imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


         imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                 imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                 setBitmap_transfer(imageView.getDrawingCache());

                 Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Touchedimagen.class);
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);


                 //Mostrar una transicion(ANIMACION) al cambiar de actividad
                 ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.scale_down);


             }
         });


     }

    }
 }
```

**Esta es el Activity**

```
//recyclerview object
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

//adapter object
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

//database reference
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

//progress dialog
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//list to hold all the uploaded images
private List<Upload>  subidas;



AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrarmemes);


    //Ocultar ActionBar
    getSupportActionBar().hide();



    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    subidas = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new Myadaptador(this,subidas); ///////////////////////////////////////Hoy

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);              ///////////////////////////////////////Hoy

    //Mostrar Progress Dialog mientras  fetching images
    progressDialog.setMessage("Espera...");
    progressDialog.show();


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constantes.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

    //adding an event listener to fetch values
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {


            //dismissing the progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //iterating through all the values in database

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);


                // Hacer que las imagenes nuevas se vean primero

                subidas.add(0,upload);



            }

            adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount()); ////////////////////HOY


            //Creando el  adapter
        //    adapter = new Myadaptador(Mostrarmemes.this, subidas);



            //agregando adapter A recyclerview

            //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });



}
```

}

**Y este es el Layout**

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_show_images"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#454545"
tools:context=".Activity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

> > ignorar
> > Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de tu activity y de tu layout

Comment: Listo @danms07 ahi esta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero te recomiendo reemplazar RelativeLayout por FrameLayout y agregar el botón que quieres. Para obtener el funcionamiento que buscas, debes hacerlo visible cuándo obtienes nuevos datos y hacerlo invisible cuándo el usuario hace clic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/activity_show_images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#454545"
    tools:context=".Activity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_see_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

El código del Activity quedaría así

```
AdView mAdView;
Button seeNew;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrarmemes);


    //Ocultar ActionBar
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    seeNew=findViewById(R.id.button_see_new);
    seeNew.setOnClickListener(this);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    subidas = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new Myadaptador(this,subidas); ///////////////////////////////////////Hoy

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);              ///////////////////////////////////////Hoy

    //Mostrar Progress Dialog mientras  fetching images
    progressDialog.setMessage("Espera...");
    progressDialog.show();


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constantes.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

    //adding an event listener to fetch values
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {


            //dismissing the progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            
            

            //iterating through all the values in database

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);


                // Hacer que las imagenes nuevas se vean primero

                subidas.add(0,upload);



            }

            adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount());
            //Si la lista carga por primera vez, no es necesario mostrar el botón
            if(subidas.size()!=snapshot.getChildrenCount()){//Sólo muestra el botón si la lista ya tenía datos y sólo se agregaron más
                seeNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } 


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });



}

public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button_see_new){
        //Recorre el recyclerView
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        //Vuelve a ocultar el botón
        seeNew.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Funciona, Gracias Bro una vez más por ayudarme , gracias a ti lo he logrado, bendiciones y cuídate por allá en México 

Comment: Cómo puedo hacer que cuando aparezca el botón se escuche un pequeño sonido???